# word form of abbreviated code

Tags: java

I have a program that I am trying to understand but there is an abbreviated code or codes that i don't understand.
 the code is

```
    double xDistance = x1 - x2 >= 0 ? x1 - x2 : x2 - x1;
    double yDistance = y1 - y2 >= 0 ? y1 - y2 : y2 - y1;
```

i read in programming books that ?: is an abbreviated form of if...then but where do i put these words in because everytime i insert or replace some code I get a syntax error.

Also are there more than one way to write the following line of code

```
(xDistance <= (w1 + w2) / 2 && yDistance <= (h1 + h2) / 2)
```

preferably replacing the && operator

thanks in advance for any assistance given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **conditional operator** `? :` is shorthand for `if-else` and works as so:

```
(condition) ? (return this if condition true) : (return this if condition false)
```

Therefore

```
double xDistance = x1 - x2 >= 0 ? x1 - x2 : x2 - x1;
```

equates to:

```
if (x1 - x2 >= 0)
   xDistance = x1 - x2;
else
   xDistance = x2 - x1;
```

The second line:

```
double yDistance = y1 - y2 >= 0 ? y1 - y2 : y2 - y1;
```

is the same thing, equates to:

```
if (y1 - y2 >= 0)
   yDistance = y1 - y2;
else
   yDistance = y2 - y1;
```

Which is storing the *absolute values* (ie. distance rather than displacement) in `xDistance` and `yDistance`. Can also be replaced with `Math.abs(x1 - x2)`, etc.

And why do you want to replace the `&&` operator in the following?

```
(xDistance <= (w1 + w2) / 2 && yDistance <= (h1 + h2) / 2)
```

If you really had to you could have (*assuming this statement belongs in an* `if` *statement*):

```
if (xDistance <= (w1 + w2) / 2)
   if (yDistance <= (h1 + h2) / 2)
      // do something
```

**EDIT:** As mentioned by [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/933682/david-brainer-banker) in the comments, `&&` is simply a *logical* AND. ie. for `X && Y`, the expression is TRUE iff both `X` is TRUE and `Y` is TRUE.

Because of this you can take advantage of *short-circuiting*, where if the first condition (`X`) is FALSE, then there is no point in the program evaluating the second (`Y`) since the expression can never be TRUE.

Comment: To follow up on on the question, "And why do you want to replace the && operator...?" The `&&` operator is a logical and. If you understand boolean logic this means that both `(xDistance <= ((w1 + w2) / 2))` _and_ `(yDistance <= ((h1 + h2) / 2))` must evaluate to true in order for the result to be true. If either one is false the whole statement is considered false. Probably the most important thing you should know about the use of `&&` instead of `&` is that `&&` "short-circuits" - meaning that if the first statement is false the second statement will not be evaluated at all.

Comment: Thanks alot for such a quick reply was extremely helpful and accurate